# How can I find a checking account that allows for automated transfers of dynamic amounts?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, checking-account, automation

Paypal provides a service called "auto-sweep" that allows you to regularly, automatically transfer the entire balance of your Paypal account into a linked bank account.  Automated transfers of a fixed monthly amount are nothing new.

I'd like to find a checking account that allows me to regularly transfer the entire balance to another account.  Are any such offerings available?  How would I find out about that feature?  Is there a list of such accounts anywhere?

Comment: I don't know, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are no such offerings.  It's hard enough to find checking accounts that don't have a minimum balance before they start charging you fees.  Banks want you to keep money in your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any financial institution has the technical ability to do this (simply called sweeps, auto sweeps, or deposit sweeps); the issue you face is finding an institution that is willing to do it for you.  I think you will have the most luck at your primary financial institution where you currently keep the majority of your banking relationship.  You will have better luck at small-town banks and credit unions.  The mega banks will likely not waver from their established policies.

Deposit sweeps are common for business accounts.  They are usually tied to a savings account, which is usually held within the same institution, however this is not a requirement.  The sweep can send money to any US bank if you can provide the routing number and account number.  The sweep will establish a peg balance, or floor balance, on the checking account.  At the end of the day, any amount above the peg is swept into the savings account automatically.

I doubt you will find what you’re asking for within an online banking system.  You will likely have to go into a branch and speak with a personal banker.  Explain to them you want to establish a sweep on your checking account and want to send the funds to another financial institution.  You will have better luck asking for a peg of $100, or some other small amount.  They may not take your request seriously if you want to completely empty the checking account to zero.